# how to use information written in a page in another page

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I'm making a website for the first time,
I made the sign in form and connected it with the database successfuly.
Now I want to use the user name that was entered in another page.

For example:
after you sign in and you press on a botton ..it takes you to the home page and says Welcome "your user name"
So how can I do this

PS: I'm using C# in visual studio 2017

Comment: It is quite a vague and open question. Really depends on your setup and the frontend technology you are using. Can you share more details about your project?

Comment: typically on SO you show your code of what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you can use Sessions or QueryString both are used for forwarding data from one page to another, session is the secure way as query string is passed from the URL. When you want to forward some private information mostly session is used and it's very easy.

For example you have the following code in your `Default.aspx` file.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtUsername" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Login" OnClick="btnLogin_Click" />
```

**1. Session** 
When user Click on the `Button` it'll call it's `OnClick` and will save the `Username` in session.

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Session["UserName"] = txtUsername.Text;
     Response.Redirect("~/Page2.aspx");
}
```

And you can retrieve the information in the next page of Page_Load event.

```
lblWelcome.Text = Session["UserName"].ToString():
```

**2. Query String**
Query string is like passing data using the URL

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Response.Redirect("~/Page2.aspx?user="+txtUsername.Text);
}
```

You can retrieve the parameter from the Link like this.

```
lblWelcome.Text = Request.QueryString["user"];
```

That's what mostly used, some programmers use Cookies to pass data from one page to another. It depends on the scenario.